# Path to chromedriver on Linux

Tags: python, linux, selenium, sudo, selenium-chromedriver

I put the chromedriver in a random folder. And wish to call it to use webdriver from selenium

But actually on: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver, says it expects the driver to be under: /usr/bin/google-chrome

I'm using dreamhost, and they told me I need to pay more to sudo /usr/bin folder. Anyway to walk around those? (namely, execute chromedriver from random location)

I tried the following (found from anther question about the same topic but no exact answer)

```
chromedriver =  "path/to/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

But it doesn't work. It gave me error: cannot find Chrome binary
Seems like another problem:(

Thanks ahead, it's gonna be very helpful! Btw I'm using Python/Flask

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist They don't assist:( Any clue I can install that on a shared server?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass chromedriver location using executable_path variable. Please find below sample code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1260")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the location of chrome driver to your PATH.

PATH=$PATH:[random folder path]

after that you should be able to run `chromedriver` and get something like:

`Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.`

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. I did set a path which isn't the one under /usr/bin. Can you take a look? It's in python/flask.